# Does attack speed influence movement speed?

Tags: league-of-legends

You can't move and attack at the same time. When you are chasing some one, you

> move -> stop -> attack -> move (with stopping and attacking happening 'almost' simultaneous).

So if you would do more attacks, you would do more stops as well.

So would someone with, lets say 1.25 attack speed cover more distance then some one with 2.5 attack. If they contentiously attack and move when possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movementspeed itself is obviously not influenced, except for Khalista.

What you are refering to is Orbwalking. You attack and break off the attack animation right after the damage is dealt/the projectile is flying.

The Attackframe is influenced by attackspeed (faster attacks = faster animation) So with higher attackspeed you can break the animation faster thus move farther with the same amount of attacks.

Note though that with faster AS you will get off more attacks in the same time which in turn reduce the distance you can move in a set time.

Comment: You last two sentence seem to contradict. " with higher attackspeed you ... move farther with the same amount of attacks." vs " with faster AS you will ... reduce the distance you can move"

Comment: @SirDuckduck It's correct though. Each individual attack will slow you down less, however you will make more attacks. Those two factors work against each other so whether you go faster or slower depends on how much you use those attacks.

Comment: @SirDuckduck if you travel by train and hold at 5 stations 10 minutes each you need the same time if you hold at 10 stations for 5 minutes each. Stations are attacks and holding times represent the wind-up. I didnt do the math on the exact difference because its also different for every champion

Comment: Thanks for the math lecture :P. But are the ratio the same? (doubling AS while halving the attack time). So that in the end they will both cover the same distance (whilst one attacking more)?

Comment: as i said no math here because im not sure of that The double as half attack time ratio is right though i belive for high attack speeds. the attack has a basic animation time, it might reach a breakpoint when the attackspeed surpasses that it or i might scale from the start. If the sacling is indeed linear the distance should be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Indirectly, yes.

Kiting is based on animation cancelling, which means you move during the animation, but not before the attack is actually issued. Attackspeed shortens the time of the attack animation, which means if you have a higher attack speed, you can interrupt the animation earlier without cancelling the attack. This results in more attacks and a "higher" movementspeed since you don't have to wait that long.

Comment: The player does need to be fast enough to do it though. Having 2.5 Attack speed is nice, but quite useless if you cannot click fast enough to reach more than 1.25. The current Kog'Maw could kite pretty well with his 5 attack speed in theory. But in reaility players can never click fast enough.

Comment: @Gnarly404 Sure, that's obvious. If the player is unskilled, he can't utilize the attack speed properly.

Answer (score -1):

## **Animation Cancel**

### No champs has the same animation

Some champions animation cancel ( Like RIVEN ) ( DON't H8 M8 )  Are saving HUGE precious wasted seconds. her animations are so slow that just the fact of cancelling it ; you can not only move a bit faster; but also actually attack faster than your ACTUAL attack speed

VS Some other champions which have a very FAST Attack animation ( Ashe, Corki and Miss Fortune etc many others; pretty much 75% champs have a faster AA anim than riven ) Where even if you do some Anim cancels the % of time you're actually cutting throu the animation doesn't make that much of a big difference. So the Actual amount of time you're saving by cancelling the animation is much much smaller which Which doesnt really give you enough timer frame to BENEFIT from the actual cancellation.

Also im not sure but i do believe that Riven is 100% the one champion where Cancelling animation will give you a very noticeable speed boost in term of Mov speed. in order to cancel your animation by the; an auto attack is not needed; if you hit your hotkey for '' Laughing '' lets say. it will instantly cancel the animation ***( TAKE NOTE. LAUGHING DOESNT MAKE YOU DO MORE DAMAGE; IT ''CANCELS'' YOUR Q ANIMATION thats it... and its funny . )***